# How do I mask the Firefox browser signature?

Tags: firefox, browser, user-agent

Does anyone know of a way to mask the Firefox browser signature, so that it looks like Internet Explorer to the rest of the world?  I know there is a plugin to use the IE rendering engine, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using Firefox.  What I'd really like to find is something that will simply replace the Firefox browser signature with something else and not affect how the browser itself renders pages, etc.  Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: Related: [How do I change Firefox's user agent via about:config?](http://superuser.com/questions/98798/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-user-agent-via-aboutconfig/98804#98804)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this User-Agent switcher plugin for Firefox: [User Agent Switcher 0.7.2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[The FF User-Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) lets you switch your user agent on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

[User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) is an addon that should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect. Lovely easy way to do it without mucking about with about:config.