# How do I change Firefox's user agent via about:config?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

My work has blocked Internet access with Firefox. I know how to change the value of “general.useragent.extra.firefox” through about:config, but when I try to change it to IE, I still can’t access any website.

I have Firefox 3.5.6 and Internet Explorer 7 installed on my desktop. Now, would I have to use the user agent that Internet Explorer 7 is currently using on my computer or can I use any Internet Explorer user agent? The user agent that Internet Explorer 7 is using right now is:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022).

Do I just copy that and use it as the user agent in Firefox?

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a User-Agent related problem, not simply the firewall blocking everything which comes from the app "Firefox"?

Comment: the firewall is probably installed on corporate gateway in this case

Comment: @Bobby: Well, the firewall uses the useragent string to know which app is actually trying to get out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That setting influences only a part of useragent string. Try the `general.useragent.override` one. This is what User Agent Switcher extension does.
Tip: this setting may be not present in fresh install. You can create it with context menu.

Also, if you think you cannot install Firefox addons when it's not allowed to browse Internet, here's another tip: just go to Firefox's addon site site and download XPI extension archive; the just open it in Firefox with File -> Open menu and it will install!

Comment: +1 I didn't even know not all the possible settings were available in about:config. Is there a list anywhere of what's all available?

Comment: So, I create the "general.useragent.override" and place the Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022) value in it?

Comment: wahle509: right

Comment: fretje: There are some docs on http://developer.mozilla.org: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Networking_Preferences, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Manager_preferences and others

Comment: Do you have a link to the "XPI extension archive" addon?

Comment: I don't remember anything that called like this, and Google suggests that there are no addons named like that. Maybe you need this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109

Answer (score 6):

Point your browser to `about:config`, right click, New -> String

Enter `general.useragent.override` and then

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022).

If your Firefox is completely blocked by the firewall, you should try some other Firefox-based browser like [Flock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flock_%28web_browser%29). Flock can use any add-on posted on Mozilla add-ons homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this using about:config.

I *do* know you can easily do this with the [User Agent Switcher add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) though.