# Google image search's carousel in PC browser

Tags: google-search

When I open google image search with Safari on iPad, if I touch one of the images, google will display a carousel where the image that I touch will be displayed on the entire screen, and then I can swipe the image to the left or right to display the previous or next image.

Google image doesn't behave like this when I open it on a PC browser like firefox or chrome. If I click on one of the images, the browser will not display a carousel but will instead go to the URL containing the image.

Is it possible to activate this carousel feature when I open google image search with PC browser like Firefox or Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, I [changed my desktop Firefox's user agent](https://superuser.com/questions/98798/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-user-agent-via-aboutconfig) to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10889244) (don't know if that's the latest, but you can always use http://whatsmyuseragent.com to see the UA string of Safari on your iPad). I then got a Tablet indication at the bottom of the Google search page, and the carousel feature you mentioned did show up in image search. However, after clicking on an image I was unable to figure out how to move to any other image using my keyboard or mouse. Maybe if you have a touch screen, the same swipe action you use on your tablet will work.

I'll update this answer if I can figure out how to enable this feature (moving between images) using a keyboard or mouse, unless of course someone else is able to do so first.

Comment: No updates so far, so I guess it is not possible to use the carousel on PCs for now.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how unfortunately. Even the UI is a bit messed up, as images seem to be layered on top of each other when I use the method above. Maybe someone will be able to make sense of the Javascript and see if the touch input can be faked and the UI 'fixed'. Once that's done, a Greasemonkey script or similar can be created to enable this alternate layout easily on desktop PCs. However, I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Cooliris is what you are looking for.  There is an extension for [Chrome](http://www.chromeextensions.org/music-videos-photos/cooliris/), [Internet Explorer](http://download.cnet.com/Cooliris-for-Internet-Explorer/3000-2356_4-10807161.html), and for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cooliris/).

Comment: Sadly, Cooliris is no longer supported on FF after 10.0

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome [agent switcher for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) is perfect for that with lots of modes built in!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try googleimageslideshow.com.  unfortunately they will show only 64 images as mentioned in their about link

update.  on chrome/mac this works

1. install the user agent switcher extension from toolshack.com
2. switch user agent to ipad
3. do the google image search
4. click on first image
5. click on the right edge of the slide show to see the next image