# Spoofing Firefox version

Tags: firefox, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I mask the Firefox browser signature?](https://superuser.com/questions/80057/how-do-i-mask-the-firefox-browser-signature)

I have a work application that validates the browser before starting to run. For Firefox it validates major version is in the range 1-3.

How can i get Firefox 6 to pretend it's Firefox 3 for the 20 minutes it'll take to get out of that website?